# Extern Variables seemingly not working "symbols not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: c, variables, global, extern

I've been searching through Stackoverflow and the web for the answer and it seems like I'm doing this correctly, however I can't get it to work.

I made a test program for using extern, (it's on xCode using the projects feature if that makes a difference). I'm trying to declare a variable, that I can access anywhere in my program, whenever I change the value of that variable, I want to be able to access the changed value.

What I've done so far is I have a header file

```
 externFile.h
```

and a

```
externFile.c
```

and of course my
main.c

In externFile.h I defined:

```
 extern int ply;
```

In main.c I have:

```
int main()
{
   int ply;
   ply = 5;
   printPly();
}
```

In externFile.c I have:

```
 void printPly(){
 printf("%d is ply.\n", ply);
 }
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
 _ply referenced from _printPly
 ld symbols not found for architecture x86_64
```

Does anyone have any sort of ideas about this?

Comment: Have you included the `externFile.h` in `externFile.c`?

Comment: ...and in main.c? It has to be in both.

Comment: @EugeneSh. My includes are just `externFile.h`. I have that included in both  `main.c` and `externFile.c`

Comment: Show the full `main.c`. I have a feeling the `ply` is local to `main`....

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. The three files involved need only be about dozen lines in total.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Here is the entirety of the main.c

Comment: @EugeneSh.
`#include "chessGame.h"`


`int main(void) {`
 

 `int ply;`
 `ply = 5;`
 

 `printPly();`
 

 
`}`

Comment: That's exactly what my feeling was talking about.

Comment: Eugene is right - `int ply` would need to be global. You can have `extern` declarations and function prototypes that lack a definition - they are ignored.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry about formatting.

Comment: How do I make it into a global variable? I thought be defining it in the header file it'd make it global?

Comment: @MatthewKerian You can edit your question. Actually you should to.

Comment: You can define a global variable outside of `main` (and any other function).

Comment: Thanks guys! I really appreciate your help! Sorry for such a stupid question.

Comment: Yes, the scope of `int ply;` is limited to `main()` - it is not visiable from outside of `main`.

Comment: Side not real quick, can I define a global variable outside of any file? For example what if I defined it inside `externFile.c` but outside of the functions in it.

Comment: Please provide an answer for this question so it can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually defined `ply` globally:

```
int main(void) 
{ 
    int ply; 
    ply = 5; 
    printPly(); 
}
```

Here, `ply` is a local variable, not a global, since it is defined inside of a function.  The `extern` line in your header file does not define the global, but **declares** it.  It says "this variable exists somewhere", but it doesn't create it.  Because there is no global defined, you get an undefined reference error.

Global variables must be defined at file scope, i.e. outside of a function:

```
int ply = 5;

int main(void) 
{ 
    printPly(); 
}
```